# how do I integrate Instagram auth login in expo react native app

Tags: react-native, expo

I am new to React Native and i am trying to implement the Instagram auth login in my app. I created the project using expo cli.

I have tried 2 solutions so far-

1. i used the instagram api provided for authentication https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id=CLIENT-ID&redirect_uri=REDIRECT-URI&response_type=code...
   this api returns me a HTML template, when i render that template inside WebView component of react native, it just shows the instagram splash screen with thumbnail icon and nothing more.
2. i used react-native-instagram-login npm module but that didn't work coz it's probably a native module and not supported by expo.

I have also looked upon auth0 module, but i guess it also is a native module itself.

Comment: Have you configured uri correctly with `webView`?

Comment: @hongdevelop i was not using the uri property of source prop, rather i was using the html property and was passing the html data returned from that auth api to html key. Using the uri property solves the issue. Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you configured uri correctly with webView?

example.js

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { WebView } from 'react-native';

class MyWeb extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <WebView
        source={{uri: 'https://github.com/facebook/react-native'}}
        style={{marginTop: 20}}
      />
    );
  }
}
```